# how can i achieve below oputput using pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

## initialize data

```
data = [[0,65247.0,53306.0,112.0,6524.0,53306.0,112.0], 
       [1,55695.0,43214.0,0.0,5569.0,43214.0,0.0], [ 2,78345.0,65189.0,0.0,7834.0,65189.0,0.0], 
        [3,16151.0,14057.0,0.0,1615.0,14057.0,0.0],[4,13960.0,12062.0,0.0,1396.0,12062.0,0.0]]
```

## creating dataframe

```
df  = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['HOUR','BSNL_WEST_SUBMITTED','BSNL_WEST_DELIVERED','BSNL_WEST_WAITING','BSNL_WE_SUBMITTED','BSNL_WE_DELIVERED','BSNL_WE_WAITING']) 
df.set_index('HOUR', inplace=True)

df.rename(columns = {'BSNL_WEST_SUBMITTED':'SUB', 'BSNL_WEST_DELIVERED':'DEL %', 
                  'BSNL_WEST_WAITING':'WAIT %','BSNL_WE_SUBMITTED':'SUB', 'BSNL_WE_DELIVERED':'DEL 
                   %','BSNL_WE_WAITING':'WAIT %'}, inplace = True)
           df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((('BSNL_WEST', 'SUB'), ('BSNL_WEST', 'DEL %'), 
               ('BSNL_WEST', 'WAIT %'), ('BSNL_NORTH', 'SUB'), ('BSNL_NORTH', 'DEL %'), ('BSNL_NORTH', 'WAIT %')))  
print(df)
```

[image]

```
             expected output:
```

[image]

Comment: check https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27772

Comment: your looking for something like multi index [checkout this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021468/can-sub-columns-be-created-in-a-pandas-data-frame)